# Diferences between Pulseaudio and Pactl, and Alsa and Amixer

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I have Pulseaudio and Alsa in my system, but I don't know the difference between them, I can control my volume with Pactl, AlsaMixer and Amixer.
Could you explain to me what each one is for, please?
And how can I chose my microphone to use etc?
I have mate installed for default, but I use bspwm. I can acces the mate sound controler from bspwm, but I don't know which system uses.

Thanks